# I have to find the maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range. please help me out

Tags: python, python-3.x

Prime Game (100 Marks)

Rax, a school student, was bored at home in the pandemic. He wanted to play but there was no one to play with. He was doing some mathematics questions including prime numbers and thought of creating a game using the same. After a few days of work, he was ready with his game. He wants to play the game with you.

GAME:

Rax will randomly provide you a range [ L , R ] (both inclusive) and you have to tell him the maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range. There are three answers possible for the given range.

There are two distinct prime numbers in the given range so the maximum difference can be found.

There is only one distinct prime number in the given range. The maximum difference in this case would be 0.

There are no prime numbers in the given range. The output for this case would be -1.

To win the game, the participant should answer the prime difference correctly for the given range.

Example:

Range: [ 1, 10 ]

The maximum difference between the prime numbers in the given range is 5.

Difference = 7 - 2 = 5

Range: [ 5, 5 ]

There is only one distinct prime number so the maximum difference would be 0.

Range: [ 8 , 10 ]

There is no prime number in the given range so the output for the given range would be -1.

Can you win the game?

Input Format
The first line of input consists of the number of test cases, T

Next T lines each consists of two space-separated integers, L and R

Constraints
1<= T <=10

2<= L<= R<=10^6

Output Format
For each test case, print the maximum difference in the given range in a separate line.

Sample TestCase 1

Input

5

5 5

2 7

8 10

10 20

4 5

Output

0

5

-1

8

0

Explanation

Test Case 1: [ 5 - 2 ] = 3

Test Case 2: [ 7 - 2 ] = 5

Test Case 3: No prime number in the given range. Output = -1

Test Case 4: [ 19 - 11 ] = 8

Test Case 5: The difference would be 0 since there is only one prime number in the given range.
This is my Python3 code:
Explain Your problem here

```
def main():
    testCase = int(input())

    while testCase>0:
        LR = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
        L = LR[0]
        R = LR[1]
        lst=[]
        flag=1
        for i in range(L,R+1):
            flag=1
            for j in range(2,i):
                if i%j==0:
                    flag=-1
                    break
            if flag == 1:
                           
                lst.append(i)

        n=len(lst)
        if n>1:
            print(max(lst)-min(lst))
        elif flag==-1:
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(0)
        testCase -=1
```

for further explanation: https://www.techgig.com/codegladiators/question/cVFhTUIxZWZJYXF0ZWlJM0loQUtvT0pybVRNREFidVFLUW5udlI1Mk1wQnp5d1dnKzhLclZDOFJCK2wrbnltLw==/1?msg_type=1

Comment: You should put questions in the body though

Comment: what exactly is Your issue? You have the code what is it it does not do?

Comment: so this is a schoolwork? well I cannot solve the problem for You and tell me what exactly is the issue with the existing code?

Comment: only the the public test cases are passed...

Comment: ok, but what exactly is the problem with Your code?

Comment: You could break it into two functions: one that determines the maximum distance in a list of sorted numbers and one that creates the sorted list of prime numbers in a given range.

Comment: but what is the issue? does the code not work?

Comment: If this is an online automatic grading system, you might be timing out in some of their test cases as you are using an extremely inefficient way to find all prime numbers in a given range. Your code would have to be killed while running if the range is e.g. 1 to 1,000,000 -- even though a properly written approach would finish in a fraction of a second.

Comment: the code isn't working! while submitting the code, it's showing that time limit exceeded and the private test cases aren't passed!

Comment: How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: You would get a dramatic speedup if you used the fact that either a number is prime or it is divisible by a prime factor which is no more than its square root. Google "Sieve of Eratosthenes" for ideas on how to implement this for an entire range. Also -- what is the point of the `elif` at the bottom of your code? At the stage `flag` is no longer relevant.

Comment: That link only gets me a 404 error.

Comment: This is a ongoing contest question, please refrain from asking till the contest is over
https://www.techgig.com/codegladiators/question

Answer (score 2):

`[4, 6]` is an example of a test case that your code fails. It should print `0`, but it prints `-1`. Testing if `flag == -1` is irrelevant -- that just tests if the last number in the range is composite. Note that `print(max(lst)-min(lst))` actually works correctly even if `n == 1`. You could replace the conditional at the bottom of the code by the simpler

```
if n >= 1:
    print(max(lst)-min(lst))
else:
    print(-1)
```

and it should pass the test cases.

As far as timing out goes, there are a couple of issues:

1. Your test for being a prime is very inefficient. In particular, you are not exploiting such simple facts as that composite numbers always have a prime divisor which is less than or equal to its square root.
2. You don't need to test the whole range. For example, suppose that L = 2 and R = 10**6. Your code tests (nearly) 1,000,000 numbers to see if they are prime. Instead, loop up from L until you find the first prime, and then loop down from R to find the largest. For L = 2, and R = 1,000,000, you would get smallest = 2 and largest = 999983 in just 18 tests, which is of course far, far less than 1,000,000 tests. My guess is that this is exactly one of their test cases, and that your code is timing out with it.

Here is my implementation of these ideas:

```
def isprime(n):
    """checks if a number >= 2 is prime"""
    if n <= 3: return True
    if n%2 == 0: return False
    d = 3
    while d*d <= n:
        if n%d == 0:
            return False
        d += 2
    return True

def alternative(L,R):
    #alternative solution
    p = 0
    for n in range(L,R+1):
        if isprime(n):
            p = n
            break
    if p == 0:
        return -1
    for n in range(R,p,-1):
        if isprime(n):
            return n - p
    return 0
```

For example:

```
>>> alternative(2,10**6)
999981
>>> alternative(370262,492226)
121740
```

Both of these computations take a small fraction of a second. The second example is, I believe, the worst-case scenario for numbers in the range stated in your question. According to [this table of prime gaps](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/GapsTable.html), 370262 is the first of 111 consecutive composites and 492226 is the last of 113 consecutive composites (so a total of 112 + 114 = 226 tests of primality required).

Comment: the alternative approach is awesome, thanks a lot @JohnColeman

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. If You have questions feel free to ask.

```
import math

# this function I did not code myself
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n > 2 and n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    max_div = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    for i in range(3, 1 + max_div, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


while True:
    try:
        num_of_test_cases = input('Number of test cases: ')
        num_of_test_cases = int(num_of_test_cases)
        if num_of_test_cases > 10 or num_of_test_cases < 1:
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Has to be an integer between 1 and 10!')

test_cases = []

for i in range(num_of_test_cases):
    while True:
        try:
            num_range = input(f'Range for test case no {i+1}:').split(' ')
            test_cases.append((int(num_range[0]), int(num_range[1])))
            if int(num_range[0]) < 2 or int(num_range[0]) > int(num_range[1]) or int(num_range[1]) > 1_000_000:
                raise ValueError
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Has to be an integer! \nFirst integer has to be bigger or equal to 2 and smaller or equal to second integer. \nSecond integer cannot be bigger than 1 000 000!')

for index, case in enumerate(test_cases):
    primes = []
    for number in range(case[0], case[1] + 1):
        if is_prime(number):
            primes.append(number)

    if len(primes) == 0:
        output = -1
    elif len(primes) == 1:
        output = 0
    else:
        output = primes[-1] - primes[0]

    print(f'Case number {index + 1} output: ', output)
```

Comment: The maximum time limit allowed for each test case is 0.50sec and @Matiiss code is working fine with 9/10 testcases, still in 1 testcase it is taking 2.5sec

Answer (score 0):

package Code;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor;

public class Question2 {

```
public Question2() {
    
}

public boolean check_prime_number(int num) {
    
    boolean sts = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
    
      if (num % i == 0) {
          sts = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    
    return sts;
}

public void find_deff(String input[]) {
    ArrayList AL=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        String temp_arr[]=input[i].split(" ");
        int start=Integer.parseInt(temp_arr[0]);
        int end=Integer.parseInt(temp_arr[1]);

         for(int j=start;j<=end;j++) {
            boolean ch=check_prime_number(j);
            if(!ch) {
                AL.add(j);
            }else {

            }
            
        }
         if(AL.size()>0) {
                int first=Integer.parseInt((AL.get(0).toString()));
                int last=Integer.parseInt((AL.get(AL.size()-1).toString()));
                if(first>last) {
                    System.out.println((first-last));
                }else {
                    System.out.println((last-first));
                }
                
            }else {
                System.out.println("-1");
            }
         AL.clear();
        
    
        
    }
    
}

public void accept_input(int n,String input[]) {
    try {
        find_deff(input);
    
        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Question2 cd=new Question2();
    String str[]= {"5 5","2 7","8 10","10 20","4 5"};
    cd.accept_input(5,str);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to exactly on the basis of question and input , hope this helps.

```
def dPrimes(L,R):
    LP=RP=c=0
    for i in range(L,R+1):
        f = 1
        for j in range(2,int(i/2+1)):
            if i%j==0:
                f=0
                break
        if f==1:
            if c == 0:
                LP=i
            RP=i
            c=c+1
    if c==0:
        return -1
    else:
        return RP-LP

n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    L,R=map(int, input().split())
    print(dPrimes(L,R))
```

Hope this is satisfactory.

Comment: Can you fix your indentations please?

Comment: ooh sorry , while coping to stack overflow it got jumbled

Answer (score 0):

```
## using c++, just got 90/100 ##

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100005
 

bool prime[MAX];
int prefix[MAX], suffix[MAX];
 
void precompute(int prefix[], int suffix[])
{
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));
 
    // Sieve of Eratosthenes
    for (int i = 2; i * i < MAX; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            for (int j = i * i; j < MAX; j += i)
                prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
 
    prefix[1] = 1;
    suffix[MAX - 1] = 1e9 + 7;
 

    for (int i = 2; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (prime[i])
            prefix[i] = i;
        else
            prefix[i] = prefix[i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = MAX - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        if (prime[i])
            suffix[i] = i;
        else
            suffix[i] = suffix[i + 1];
    }
}
 

int query(int prefix[], int suffix[], int L, int R)
{
    if (prefix[R] < L || suffix[L] > R){
    cout<<"-1"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{
            if(prefix[R] - suffix[L]>0){
            cout<<prefix[R] - suffix[L]<<endl;
        }
        else if(prefix[R] - suffix[L]==0){
            cout<<"0"<<endl;
        }

        return prefix[R] - suffix[L];

    }
}
 
int main()
{
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    int L[q];
    int R[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
    cin>>L[i]>>R[i];
    }
    precompute(prefix, suffix);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        query(prefix, suffix, L[i], R[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some exaplanation

Comment: One test case is failing because as there is a runtime error. So change MAX  from 100005 to 1000005. Then all test cases will be passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd slove it in this way, it has passed all the test cases given.

```
def main():
    testCase = int(input())
    def isprime(n):
        if n<=1:
            return False
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n%i == 0:
                return False
        return True

    while testCase>0:
        LR = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
        lst=[]
        first = LR[0]
        last = LR[1]
        for i in  range(first,last+1):
            if isprime(i):
                lst.append(i)
                break
            else:
                i=i+1
        for i in range(last,first,-1):
            if isprime(i):
                lst.append(i)
                break
            else:
                i=i+1



        n=len(lst)
        if n>1:
            print(max(lst)-min(lst))
        elif n==1:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(-1)

        testCase -=1
main()
```

Hope you found this helpful.